# How to setup a "module" command in unix to add software package to $PATH?

Tags: bash, shell, module

I use a lot of computing clusters and these often use a module system for making software packages available. Basically, you use the module command like `module load sample_software` and the `sample_software` path is added to `$PATH`. On a cluster, this command can be invoked during interactive usage and job submission usage.

I have a linux box with PBS/Torque queueing system installed so that I can sandbox software for later use on clusters. I need a very similar module system on this box. I started by making a file called `modules.sh` in my `/etc/profile.d/ directory that looks like this:

```
module()
{
if [ $2 == "softwareX" ]; then
    PATH=$PATH:/home/me/dir/softwareX
    export PATH
fi
}
```

I then put the following line in my `.bash_profile` script:

```
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
```

Now, this works great for the following usages: 1) If I submit a job and my job script uses `module load softwareX`, no problem, the job runs perfectly. 2) If I am working interactively on the command line and I type `module load softwareX`, then the path to softwareX is loaded into my `$PATH` and everything works great.

However, this doesn't work for the following situation: If I make a simple bash script that contains the line `module load softwareX`, when the bash script executes I get an error. For example, here is my bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $PATH
module load softwareX
echo $PATH
```

When I execute this I receive the error `script.sh: line 3L module: command not found`

...and the `$PATH` never changes. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem to work in all three situations? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bash script won't invoke your startup files. You have to do that explicitly.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

> Invoked non-interactively
>
> > When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
> >
> > ```
> >    if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> > ```
> >
> > but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.
> >
> > As noted above, if a non-interactive shell is invoked with the --login option, Bash attempts to read and execute commands from the login shell startup files.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sub-shell, you create a new environment. When you exit back to your existing shell, you lose that environment.

I suspect this is what is going on with your module function call. If you added `echo $PATH` to the bottom of your module function, do you see the PATH get changed while inside the function, but changes again when you leave the function? If so, the problem is a sub-shell issue:

What you SHOULD do is have your module function print out the new path, and then do this:

```
PATH=$(module load softwareX)
```